# Loading GHCi on MacOSX Yosemite

Tags: haskell

I recently started Haskell and downloaded the Haskell platform from the official website. Most tutorials I've been looking at have given screenshots of what the interpreter should look like when loading. For example, the book "Learn you a Haskell for a great good" claims this should show up:

```
GHCi, version 6.8.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help  
Loading package base ... linking ... done.  
Prelude>
```

However, when I do it, I don't get the "Loading package base..." statement. Am I missing a download? Also, is this all I need to get started with Haskell? I've seen the terms "gcc" and "cabal" thrown around, but I'm not sure what those are. Thank you!

Comment: "Am I missing a download?" Nope, the message just got more concise in more recent versions. "I've seen the terms 'gcc' [...]" You probably mean GHC, the Haskell compiler of which GHCi is a component. "[...] and 'cabal' [...]" cabal refers to the tool with which you install extra libraries. If you have just begun "Learn you a Haskell" there is no need to look into it right now.

Comment: @duplode 
 
I am referring to gcc as a term frequently paired with xcode. I vaguely recall doing something with gcc and homebrew when I was installing a brewed python a couple months ago. As for the cabal thing, I'm going to guess I'll need that because I'm taking an advanced functional programming course soon, so where can I get more info on that? Thank you for the swift reply!

Comment: @Nitin gcc is a C compiler (well, technically it's a collection of compilers which includes a C compiler). On modern OS X, 'gcc' is an alias for clang (which is a different C compiler, confusingly). It is used internally by GHC, so you will almost certainly not have to worry about it at all.

Comment: @Nitin As for cabal, [this page](http://katychuang.com/cabal-guide/) and the links therein are a nice starting point. But again, I don't think you need to worry about it *right now* - not until you get the hang of the basics and feel like starting your own projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751851/duplode) commented, the `Loading package base` message was removed in newer versions of GHCi.

GCC is a collection of compilers that should be pre-installed. Get the version with `gcc --version` on the command line.

However, as commented, you may be referring to **GHC**, the **G**lasgow **H**askell **C**ompiler (of which GHCi is an interactive version), which should be installed alongside GHCi. If it is installed, the below is to be expected:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.2
```

Cabal is a package manager that should be installed alongside GHC and GHCi. You can run `cabal --version` to test if it's installed.

---

Relevant links:

- [The GHC homepage](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/)
- [The cabal homepage](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/)
- [The GCC homepage](https://gcc.gnu.org/)
- [A guide to GHCi](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html)

Comment: I just ran `brew install ghc cabal-install`. Did I accidentally install two versions of ghc?

Comment: @Nitin I don't think so. Running that wouldn't make any problems. I think. Hopefully. I would check the versions to make sure that everything works.

Comment: The versions are the same but I'm concerned that there are two copies of Haskell on my machine